# Actionbar buttons not working

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am new to android development.I have made an app where the `MainActivity` consists of a `Gridview` with images and `ActivityTwo` is the `fullscreen` view of the selected image.I am trying to add a back button on the actionbar.The icon is visible but it is not clickable.Also i tried to add other menu items which are also visible but nothing happens on touching them.I have also tried adding onClickListener to the menu items as suggested in some posts but it didn't seem to work.

Below is the ActivityTwo code.

```
public class ActivityTwo extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

    protected int currentPosition;
    Button share,back;
    ImageView imageView;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);
        toolbar= (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);      
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        share = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        share.setOnClickListener(this);
        back=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        back.setOnClickListener(this);




        // get intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Selected image id
        final int position = i.getExtras().getInt("position");

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                currentPosition = arg0;

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });





    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if
        (id==R.id.home)
        {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        Integer[] icons = MainActivity.mThumbIds;

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return icons.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((ImageView) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Context context = ActivityTwo.this;
            imageView = new ImageView(context);
            //ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            // int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
            // R.dimen.padding_large);
            imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            imageView.setImageResource(icons[position]);
            imageView.setTag(position);
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
            return imageView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(v==share){
        ImageView Imgv = (ImageView)viewPager.findViewWithTag(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
        Drawable mDrawable = Imgv.getDrawable();
        Bitmap mBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)mDrawable).getBitmap();

        String path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), 
            mBitmap, "Image Description", null);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);




            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            shareIntent.setType("image/*");

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));    }
        if(v==back)
        {
            finish();
        }

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code to your toolbar for navigating back

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
    }
});
```

For another item in your toolbar

```
@Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     switch (item.getItemId()) {
         case R.id.action_settings:
             Toast.makeText(context, "setting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             break;
         case R.id.action_share:
             Toast.makeText(context, "share", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             break;

     }
 }
```

Hope this help

Comment: I've tried setting navigation icon on the toolbar and then setting onClickListener but it also does not seem to work.The back icon is visible but the click does not work.

Answer (score 0):

To make your app icon "clickable" as a back button, your Activities must follow a parent-child hierarchy.

Example:

- Activity A is your main Activity.
- Pressing something (say a ListView item or GridView item) will start Activity B.

In this way Activity A is what's called a parent Activity to Activity B.

You define this in XML in your manifest like so:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.android.ActivityA"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_a" />

<activity
    android:name="com.example.android.ActivityB"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_b"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.android.ActivityA">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.android.ActivityA" />
</activity>
```

This will make the app icon appear with a back arrow ( < ) to the left of it.

We then must handle the click event.

We so this from within our **onOptionsItemSelected** method in Activity B like so:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        // Create an intent to start Activity A.
        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityA.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

***android.R.id.home*** is the ID of the click event we are listening for.

Sometimes you may wish to simulate a back button press instead of starting Activity A fresh with an intent. You could achieve that like so:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        // Simulate back button press.
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: I've tried this previously but it does not seem to work.It looks like the ActionBar fails to register touch.

Comment: Are you sure you have the **onCreateOptionsMenu** method overriden in your Activity?